# Microsoft Edge: Why does the cursor jump before a letter?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, contenteditable

**Overview:** In the following code, there is an editable div element, which in turn contains a span element. The span element will have a background of orange and it is non-editable. Span element has the current content as "Time"

**Note:** I have extracted this part of code from my project and certain characters like "&zwnj ;" are already there. My main intention is to reproduce this issue through a simple example

**Issue:** In Microsoft edge, when I type a letter "d" after "Time", I notice that the cursor goes before the letter. When I further type some letters "ddd", the non-editable span element gets edited.

**Question:**

1) Why does the cursor jump before the letter in Microsoft Edge?

2) What is the best way to prevent the above scenario from happening?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
         span {
            background-color: orange;
         }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div contenteditable="true">&zwnj;<span contenteditable="false">Time</span>&zwnj;</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```